# Adding a class to the links in wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation

I'm working on a new wordpress site and I'm building it with the [Foundation framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/ui.php). I'd like to add the class "main" to the links in the navigation that is built with wp_nav_menu. Eventually, I'll probably want to add the class "has-flyout" to others. Any idea on how to do this? I'm assuming I need to extend Walker (or can I do this with 'items_wrap'?), but that seems like overkill.

Currently, I have:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary_navigation',
    'container' =>false,
    'menu_class' => '',
    'echo' => true,
    'before' => '',
    'after' => '',
    'link_before' => '',
    'link_after' => '',
    'depth' => 0,
    'items_wrap' => '<ul class="nav-bar">%3$s</ul>'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
...
'menu_class' => 'main-menu',
...
```

And in your CSS (if that is what you want) access it like so:

```
ul.main-menu li { background: white; }
```

To add your "flyout" list-items maybe you could look into [superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples)? That system automatically adds "sf-with-ul" classes to list-items containing dropdowns.